# Access remote drive from client with remote desktop in Windows

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I'm connecting to my work machine from home via Remote Desktop.  I want to access (map) a server hard drive from (to) my home machine.  Is this possible?

#### Background

I have a Logitech gaming mouse.  For some reason, in Visual Studio, pressing the Back button on my mouse doesn't work when editing at a .js file, as it does while editing a .cs file.  However, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> does work.  I want to create a profile for my mouse that changes the Back button to instead do the key combination, but for the profile to automatically change, I have to give it a file path to the executable, which is on the remote drive.  So, unfortunately, I can't simply access a local drive from my remote machine; it must be the other way around.

I don't know if it matters, but my local (home/client) machine is running Windows 8.1, and my server (work) machine is running Windows 7 SP1.

#### Edit

I <strike>may</strike> have already found a solution (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/87fb8c65-d1db-49e9-a068-d62a222a4ae7), but I'm still interested in my original question.

Comment: This definitely looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Actually, I may have already found another solution, but I'm still interested in my question.  I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Do you mean you wish to [map a network drive](http://www.wealthyaffiliaterevolution.com/how-to-map-a-remote-server-to-a-drive-in-windows-explorer/)?

Comment: Unfortunately, my home machine is not VPN'd, so my RDP server is not on the same network.  Does remote desktop create a psuedo-VPN?  That is, is there a keyword or something that lets me access `\\[keyword]\c` from my home machine?  I already tried accessing it via the server's machine name.

Comment: I don't know about that, but if you're allowed to install software on your work PC, TeamViewer has a VPN component that allows you to share files between both computers.

Comment: I can, but I'd rather not.  It's just one more thing, you know?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the other way around if that helps?

http://www.serverintellect.com/support/techfaq/drive-rdp/

Comment: It's helpful if you post the important stuff from the links in your answer because links tend to get broken in the future.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work because the Logitech software requires me to find the executable from the client side.  Although, another solution might have been just to install the mouse software on the server.

Comment: @dfoverdx you've got this all wrong. The mouse is connected to your home computer so installing the mouse driver on the remote computer wouldn't solve anything. Also, if you're still looking to solve the mouse problem, I'd reiterate that this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Vinayak Good point about the software.  I did already find a fix with the VS Extension I posted in an edit.  But I am still interested in my original question.